# A special kind of thank you

Tags: cipher

I typed up a thank you message this morning, but I accidentally ran a cipher on it and can't remember how to unscramble it.

> vh 5cq pajmn lujbbaxxv fjclqrwp cnaaxa dwoxum xw cqn cnunerbrxw. R
> anvnvkna wxc anjuuh cwmnabcjwmrwp cqn rvyurljcrxwb, *jc orabc*. Jb cqn
> kaxjmljbc yaxpanbbnm, R anvnvkna kanjtrwp mxfw rw cnjab jacna
> anjurirwp cqjc R qjm uxenm xwnb cqjc fxdum kn rwexuenm rw fqjc fjb cx
> lxvn. Xw cqrb mjh rw qrbcxah, vjwh vxxwb jpx, R bjc rw
>
> yjbbnm. Cqn bcadppunb cqjc cqn bnaerln vnvknab nwmdanm, oxanena
> dwkntwxfwbc cx j ejbc vjsxarch xa cqxbn fqx frcwnbbnm cqnra bcadppunb
> nexuen. Vjwh uxbc uxenm xwnb cqjc mjh, xcqnab uxbc cqnv jb crvn
>
> j vxvnwc cx cqjwt cqxbn fqx bnaenm knoxan vn, cqxbn fqx bnaenm frcq
> vn, jwm cqxbn fqx qjen bnaenm, xa fruu bnaen jacna vn. Cqjwt hxd juu,
> oxa qjerwp cqn kajenah cx ydc hxda urenb xw cqn urwn, oxa cqn
> bjlarorlnb hxd vjmn, cqn uxen hxd'en uxbc, cqn crvn hxd'uu wnena pnc
> kjlt; juu rw cqn wjvn xo yaxcnlcrwp xcqnab. Cxmjh, jc cqn jpn xo 30, R
> fxdum urtn cx cjtn
>
> hxd. Cqjwt

Can you help me unscramble my thank you message?

Comment: Terng zrffntr @Taco. Gunax lbh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two steps you need to follow to decrypt your message:

> 1. Run it through a rot-17 Caesar shift (as it's encoded in **rot-9**, where the letters have been shifted **9 positions** along in the alphabet);
>
>  2. Move the last **11 words** of each paragraph to the front.

It soon becomes clear why you have chosen this combination of numbers in your encryption process, as the plaintext contains:

> a message relating to your personal remembrance of the events that unfolded on **11 September (9/11)** in New York 20 years ago.

The fully deciphered message (a few corrected typos indicated in square brackets) reads:

> *On this day in history, many moons ago, I sat in my 5th grade classroom watching terror unfold on the television. I remember not really [u]nderstanding the implications, at first. As the broadcast progressed, I remember breaking down in tears a[f]ter realizing that I had loved ones that would be involved in what was to come.*
>
>  *Many lost loved ones that day, others lost them as time passed. The struggles that the service members endured, forever unbeknownst to a vast majority or those who witnessed their struggles evolve.*
>
>  *Today, at the age of 30, I would like to [take a] moment to thank those who served before me, those who served with me, and those who have served, or will serve a[f]ter me. Thank you all, for having the bravery to put your lives on the line, for the sacrifices you made, the love you've lost, the time you'll never get back; all in the name of protecting others.*
>
>  *Thank you.*